# Unit Testing action hook

Tags: plugin-development, unit-tests

I want to perform unit tests on a Class, my goal is: I want to check if the plugin is activated or not by using the function: `is_plugin_active`

```
class WC_Custom_Variable_Products_Dependencies {
    public function __construct() {
          add_action( 'admin_init', [$this, 'check_environment']);
    }
    public function check_environment(){
          return is_plugin_active( 
                    'woocommerce-custom-variable-products/woocommerce-custom-variable-products.php' 
                 );
    }
}
```

CLass de test :

```
require_once 'class-wc-custom-variable-products-dependencies.php';
class WC_Custom_Variable_Products_DependenciesTest extends WP_UnitTestCase {

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->class_instance = new WC_Custom_Variable_Products_Dependencies();
    }

    public function test_check_environment(){

        $result = $this->class_instance->check_environment();
        $this->assertTrue($result);
    }
```

The assertion return always False  .

My plugin is activated, and the function `is_plugin_active` returns True if I execute it from the browser:

```
add_action('admin_init', function(){

     var_dump(is_plugin_active( 
                        'woocommerce-custom-variable-products/woocommerce-custom-variable-products.php' 
    ));
});
```

I think the `admin_init` hook is not executed in the test. is it true or not?

Comment: The hook you're testing doesn't make much sense, actions such as `admin_init` don't return values

Comment: The `check_environment()`  method verify if the plugin is already active or not, so that's it hooked `admin_init`. I do not test the return value of `admin_int`, I test the `check_environment()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why. here is the solution: you have to activate the plugin in the `tests / bootstrap.php` file:

```
$GLOBALS[ 'wp_tests_options' ] = array(
        'active_plugins' => array(
                'YOUR-PLUGIN/YOUR-PLUGIN.php'
        )
)
```